# Draw a triangle given $A-B=90$(degree) and length of $AC,BC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Draw a triangle given $A-B=90$(degree) and length of $AC,BC$.

**My attempt**:I thought It would be a good idea to draw a right angle so I made the picture below:

[image]

But I don't know how to find the appropriate point on the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Law of sines for $\Delta ABC$ we obtain
$$\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\frac{a}{\sin(90^{\circ}+\beta)}$$ or
$$\tan\beta=\frac{b}{a}$$
and the angle with this measure easy to construct.

Comment: But I need a straightedge-and-compass construction.

Comment: @Taha Akbari By segments $a$ and $b$ you can construct an angle with measured-angle  $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

From 
\begin{align}
\frac{b}{\sin\beta}
&=
\frac{a}{\sin(90^\circ+\beta)}
=
\frac{a}{\cos\beta}
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align}
\tan\beta&=\frac{b}{a}
,\quad
\sin\beta=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
,\\
2\,R&=\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
.
\end{align}

$\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A_1BC$
are inscribed in the same circle with the radius $R$:

[image]

Comment: But I need a straightedge-and-compass construction

Comment: @Taha Akbar: It's trivial: you already have a $\triangle A_1BC$. 
Find $O$ as a middle point of $A_1B$, draw a circle $(O,|OB|)$,
then draw a circle $(C,|CA_1|)$ and find $A$ at the intersection.